# how to send the content of a node in xml to another page using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

how to send the content of a node in xml to another page using php?

page.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1  target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "http://d-toma.netne.net/Data.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$title=$xml->page[0]->title;
$image=$xml->page[0]->image;

echo("<div class=\"main\"><img src=\"$image\"/>$title</div>");


  for($i = 1; $i<4;$i++){
$title=$xml->page[$i]->title;
$image=$xml->page[$i]->image;



    $title= $xml->page[$i]->title;
//$title=$xml->page->content->asXML();
$html .="<div class=\"sec\"><img src=\"$image\"/>$title</div>";

 }

echo $html;

?>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

i just want when i click on the div to open another page and put the content of the node i clicked on it
please help me thank you
i just tryed every thing but i dont know how to solve this problem

Comment: you'd need an `<a>` tag for the clicking, unless you want to use JS, and then somehow pass the fetched content as a query parameter, or pass an ID of some sort so that other page can re-fetch the same information.

Comment: i know but i dont know how to do that how to pass the content can u help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next solution is same you require, only I use jQ:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
    <header>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            .container {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .menu {
                float: left;
                width: 25%;
            }

            .menu a {
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .page {
                float: left;
                width: 75%;
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="page">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var $pageCollection;

            function buildMenu($xmlDoc) {
                var $menu = $('div.menu > ul'),
                    $pageDetail = $('div.page'),
                    items = [];

                // Get page collection
                $pageCollection = $xmlDoc.find('page');

                $pageCollection.each(function (index, element) {
                    var $page = $(element),
                        item = $('<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-index="' + index + '">' 
                            + $page.find('title').html()
                            + '<br />' + $page.find('desc').html() + '</a></li>');

                    items.push(item);
                });

                // Show page 0 for default
                var $firstPage = $pageCollection.first(),
                    $contentPage = $firstPage.find('content').html();

                $pageDetail.html($contentPage);

                // Add event handlers
                $menu.append(items);
                $menu.on('click', 'a', onAnchorClick);
            }

            function getXml(url, callback) {
                $.get(url, function (response) {
                    var $xmlDoc = $(response);

                    callback($xmlDoc);
                });
            }

            function onAnchorClick(event) {
                var $pageDetail = $('div.page'),
                    $anchor = $(event.currentTarget),
                    index = $anchor.attr('data-index');

                // Clear previous content
                $pageDetail.empty();

                // Show current page
                var $currentPage = $pageCollection.eq(index),
                    $contentPage = $pageCollection.find('content').html();

                $pageDetail.html($contentPage);
            }

            $(function () {
                var url = 'http://d-toma.netne.net/Data.xml';

                getXml(url, buildMenu);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This solution load using AJAX the XML file, and parse this find for `content` tag. The anchor in menu div save index position in XML, using it to select current page in XML page collection.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions. The important thing to remember is that in the header bellow (`header('Location: http://www.yoururl.com/displaypage.php');`) must be the same url you acessed the site with along with /displaypage.php.

So if you accessed with 'yoururl.com' then must be: `header('Location: http://yoururl.com/displaypage.php');` but if you accessed with 'www.yoururl.com' then must be: `header('Location: http://www.yoururl.com/displaypage.php');`. This is nescessary to preserve your access to the session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['TitleImageInfo'] = array();    

for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {

    $title=$xml->page[$i]->title;
    $image=$xml->page[$i]->image;

    //Add title, image html to the $_SESSION['TitleImageInfo'] session array.
    $_SESSION['TitleImageInfo'] = "<div class=\"sec\"><img src=" . $image . "/>" . $title . "</div>";
}


header("Location: http://www.yoururl.com/displaypage.php");
```

On displaypage.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    for($i = 1; $i < count($_SESSION['TitleImageInfo']); $i++) {
        echo($_SESSION['TitleImageInfo'][i]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: i think its going to work but i need to click on some a tag to open it to show me the content on the display page thanks