# adding onclick event in xml result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

This is the main HTML page.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="categories">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>

<script src="script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

this is the xml page

```
<CategoriesRoot>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Beverages</CategoryName>
        <Description>Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beer, and ale</Description>
    </Categories>
</CategoriesRoot>
```

and this is the js page

```
$.ajax({

    url:'categories.xml',
    dataType:'xml',
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find('CategoriesRoot Categories').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).find('CategoryName').text();

            $('.categories ul').append(
                $('<li/>',{
                    text: name


                })

            );

        });

    },
    error: function(){
        $('.categories').text('failed');

    }

});
```

I can read the xml file in my main page, but what i want to do is, when i click the CategoryName like Beverages, it will display the Description(Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beer, and ale) on the right of the main page.
I am new for html,please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I Share with you an answer I gave in another post, but it can help you:

[how to send the content of a node in xml to another page using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449857/how-to-send-the-content-of-a-node-in-xml-to-another-page-using-php/25451521#25451521)

Greetings

**Edition**

I put sample code on next [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz35zcob/2/) sample. The code is very simple. This work as follow:

1. You call AJAX request to get XML (`line 30`).
2. In the response function (`line 33`), you call to function that build you menu.
3. Into build function, you get all categories (`line 9`).
4. Next, you iterate over all categories and build list items (`line 11 to line 17`).
5. And finally, you to list an event handler (`line 27`) to catch click event on anchor tag into list.

Comment: Hi Guzman, coz i am very new in this field, i can not understand your code very clearly...sorry for that! if you can edit on my code, it will be much more better for me! thank you so much!!!